# I want to begin with arduino programming

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to start programming with the Arduino Uno, but I don't know where to start or what a good start is. I can program a bit in c#, but I red that you have to program in c++.

Any idea's where to start?

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to Arduino Stack Exchange. You should do some basic research before you ask a question. This question is a duplicate and a question that can be resolved with a quick Google on: "Arduino get started".

Comment: Also, you might pick up a book and/or starter kit, they'll get you started very fast!

Comment: Yes, you are right @Paul, but i wanted to know the opinion of other programmers.

Comment: Good point, it would be better to ask in chat then (I believe you can't use chat yet though) or look at the duplicate questions: `http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18206/how-to-get-started`. You also should've stated that you were looking for opinions ;) Just take a little time to check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sure, thanks for your tip! I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other suggestions are great.
If you want to make a more "academic" approach, I can recommend two courses on [Coursera](http://www.coursera.org):

- [The Arduino Platform and C Programming](https://www.coursera.org/learn/arduino-platform/)
- [Interfacing with the Arduino](https://www.coursera.org/learn/interface-with-arduino)

I've followed and completed these 2 courses, and I think they were great fun. They give a light-weight introducton to the Arduino, with only a little time consumption needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can purchase some great starter kits too:

They're easy to search for, here's a few that popped up right away:

http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoStarterKit

[http://www.amazon.com/Kuman-Project-Complete-Starter-breadboard/dp/B016D5KUHS/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016D5KUHS)

And here's one that I own, and I've recommended to other people:

http://www.microcenter.com/product/458578/Arduino_Compatible_Maker_Kit_with_LCD_Display

If you have a microcenter or radio shack or Fry's in your area, they all stock a variety of different starter kits.

Comment: I would like to add that you should go with one of the kits that has a book/guide with projects along with it. With a heap of components, it can be very difficult to get started. If there are some fun projects included, it will really motivate better.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of Arduino. You can start by going directly to the Arduino Site -> [Learning & tutorials](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/HomePage). Also the internet full of 100's, if not 1000's of information and tutorials.

Comment: Do you have an example of a good tutorial, one that you think is good

Comment: Google Arduino Blink Tutorial -> https://www.google.com/search?q=Arduino+Blink+Tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: @Safwan If i answered your question, please mark the answer as ANSWERED. Thanks